# ReCharts xaxis Label now showing with custom domain

Tags: reactjs, recharts

Maybe someone can help. I'm changing charting library from react-vis to recharts as react-vis is now deprecated.

I'm having trouble setting a custom domain and having the xaxis show correctly.

I want it to show [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13] representing hours 5am - 1pm. Because its only 12 o'oclock, I don't yet have data for 12 or 13, but I still want to show these hours in the domain, otherwise the charts look warped at the start of the day, and also when there is no activity in a certain hour, its missed completely.

I've put the chart data as a variable to show how I receive it.

It all works fine except it doesn't show my labels on the axis. I've tried tickformatter, changing type, interval etc. nothing seems to bring the labels up...

Can anyone advise? :)

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BarChart, Bar, XAxis, ResponsiveContainer
} from 'recharts';

const BarReCharts = (props) => {
    const {color,data} = props

    //live data
    /* let chartData = []
    data.map(item => {
        chartData.push({x: Number(item.hour), y: item.units})
    }) */


    let chartData = [
        {x: 5, y: 1508},
        {x: 6, y: 107},
        {x: 7, y: 325},
        {x: 8, y: 439},
        {x: 9, y: 982},
        {x: 10, y: 1562},
        {x: 11, y: 50},
        ]

    const Label = (props) => {
          const {x, y, value} = props;

             return (
             <text 
                x={x} 
                y={y} 
                dx={"5.5%"}
                dy={-4} 
                fontSize='10' 
                fontWeight="bold"
                fill={"#181818"}
                textAnchor="middle">{value}</text>
             )
      }


    return (
        <ResponsiveContainer width={"100%"} height={200}>
            <BarChart
                data={chartData}
                height={100}
                barCategoryGap={1}
                margin={{
                top: 15, right: 5, left: 5, bottom: -5,
                }}
            >
                <XAxis
                    tick={{fontSize: 8}}
                    dataKey="x"
                    type="number"
                    domain={[4.5,13.5]}
                    ticks={[5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]}
                />
                <Bar dataKey="y" fill={color} label={<Label />}/>
            </BarChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
    );
}

export default BarReCharts
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a codesandbox for the same, I can see the labels

https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-barchart-nf0yk

Comment: Interesting, it seems to be the ResponsiveContainer that is causing it to disappear...I will have to do some more playing around... appreciate response...interesting!